# Equivalent of “pass” in Ruby

Tags: ruby, keyword

In python there is a `pass` keyword for defining an empty function, condition, loop, ...
Is there something similar for Ruby?

Python Example:

```
def some_function():
    # do nothing
    pass
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You always have `end` statements, so `pass` is not needed.

Ruby example:

```
def some_function()
    # do nothing
end
```

## Ruby 3.0

[As of Ruby 3.0, so-called "`end`less" method definitions are now supported](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2020/12/25/ruby-3-0-0-released/) -- we no longer require `end` statements with every single method definition. This means the most concise way of expressing an empty method like the example above is now arguably something like this:

```rb
def some_function = nil
```

Alternatively, there has always been an uglier one-line option using the much-hated semicolon:

```rb
def some_function; end
```

Note that this doesn't really change anything about the first solution except how the code can be written.

Answer (score 68):

No, there is no such thing in Ruby. If you want an empty block, method, module, class etc., just write an empty block:

```
def some_method
end
```

That's it.

In Python, every block is *required* to contain *at least* one statement, that's why you need a "fake" no-op statement. Ruby doesn't *have* statements, it only has expressions, and it is perfectly legal for a block to contain zero expressions.

Answer (score 31):

`nil` is probably the equivalent of it:

```
def some_function
  nil
end
```

It's basically helpful when ignoring exceptions using a simple one-line statement:

```
Process.kill('CONT', pid) rescue nil
```

Instead of using a block:

```
begin
  Process.kill('CONT')
rescue
end
```

And dropping `nil` would cause syntax error:

```
> throw :x rescue
SyntaxError: (irb):19: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input
        from /usr/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

**Notes:**

`def some_function; end; some_function` returns `nil`.

`def a; :b; begin; throw :x; rescue; end; end; a;` also returns `nil`.

Comment: THIS is the solution. Nice work. I was looking for a ? : way to do nothing: `x == true ? y = false : #Do nothing if false` became `x == true ? y = false : nil` which worked perfectly!

Comment: Is there a reason you couldn't just do `y = false if x`?

Answer (score 11):

**Single line functions and classes**

```
def name ; end

class Name ; end
```

works fine for **pseudocode**.

As answered before everything in ruby is an **expression** so it is fine to leave it **blank**.

```
def name
end

class Name
end
```

**A ruby alternative for python programmers who love the pass keyword**

```
def pass
end

# OR

def pass; end
```

Note that it is useless to do this in Ruby since it allows empty methods but if you're that keen on `pass`, this is the simplest and cleanest alternative.

and now you can use this function inside any **block** and it will work the same.

```
def name
   pass
end

# OR

class Name
   pass
end
```

Keep in mind that pass is a function that returns, so it is up to you how you can use it.

Comment: [Rubocop](https://rubocop.org/) prefers `def name; end`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to use it freely with any number of arguments, you have to have a small trick on the arguments:

```
def gobble *args, &pr; end
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, in Ruby you can just leave a method body empty. However, this could prove a bit different than what Python accomplishes with `pass`.

In Ruby, everything is an object. The absence of value, which some programming languages indicate with `null` or `nil` is actually an object of `NilClass` in Ruby.

Consider the following example (in `irb`):

```
class A
  def no_op
  end
end

A.new.no_op
# => nil
A.new.no_op.class
# => NilClass
A.new.no_op.nil?
# => true
```

Here's Ruby's [NilClass documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/NilClass.html) for reference.

I believe Python's `pass` is used mainly to overcome the syntactic limitations of the language (indentation), although I'm not that experienced in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby's equivalent to `pass` can be `()`.

```
if 1 == 1
   ()
else
   puts "Hello"
end

=> nil
```

```
lambda do
    ()
end.call  
=> nil
```

You can also use it as part of `condition ? true-expr : false-expr` ternary operator.