# ruby: do nothing (dummy) function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coding-style

When working with ruby on rails code, what is the conventional way (or most elegant way) to let rails do nothing? 
For example when debugging and commenting out a line where there has to be a statement:

```
begin
  #some_commented_out_function
rescue => e
[...]
end
```

Is there a dummy function I quickly can put in instead of the commented out line? What is the convention for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Equivalent of “pass” in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13452624/equivalent-of-pass-in-ruby)

Comment: Yes, a one word noop like pass was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby doesn't have a `pass` or no-op statement. In your example, that code would work as written, with or without a comment.

If you'd like to make it explicit, a line with just `nil` or a comment explaining the method would probably be considered conventional.